# Logic help - Find the series of elements in ascending order

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, logic

Given a set of array, it has different values. i have to display the series of numbers in ascending order only

(for example)

*if input is*

**{45,50,55,60,45,40,50,55}**

*then output should be*

**{45,50,55,60,40,50,55}**

My code below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] values = { 45, 50, 55, 60, 45, 40, 50, 55 };



    for (int i = 0; i < values.length-1; i++) {

        if(values[i]<values[i+1]){

            System.out.println(values[i]);

        }

    }

}
```

It displays the output as **{45, 50, 55, 40, 50}**. 4th element **60** and last element **55** is not getting displayed with my logic.

Can anyone help to change this logic to display the right output?

The output should be 
**{45,50,55,60,40,50,55}**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] values = { 45, 50, 55, 60,59,58, 45, 40, 50, 55,54,53,55 };

    //keep track so that previous smaller element is also included
    boolean pair=false;
    for (int i = 1; i < values.length;i++ ) {

        if(values[i-1]<values[i]){
            if(!pair){
                System.out.println(values[i-1]);
                pair=true;
            }
            System.out.println(values[i]);
        }else{
            pair=false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**As your output**, just edit your code as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int[] values = { 45, 50, 55, 60, 45, 40, 50, 55 };
    int temp = 0; // create a temp variable
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if(values[i] > temp){// if satisfied; print
            System.out.print(values[i]+", ");
            temp = values[i];
        } else {// else prepare for next loop
            temp = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
45, 50, 55, 60, 40, 50, 55,
```

Comment: Please check the logic if input is int[] values = {50, 45, 50, 55, 60, 45, 40, 50, 55 };

Answer (score 0):

What you actually do is compare the current value with the next value and print the smaller one.
So **[1, 4, 5, 8]** will actually work.
But **[4, 8, 5, 7]** won't because you will only compare **4** and **8** which prints **4** then **8** and **5** which prints nothing then **5** and **7** which prints **5**. Result : **[4, 5]**.

What you need to do, is first to sort the array in ascending order, then display it like any array.
There are many ways to sort an array, see the [Bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) algorithm or you can find your own way to sort them.